# Proving that $\gcd(n!,\ n+1)=1$ or $n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

For any positive integer $n$ I need to prove that $\gcd(n!,\ n+1)=1$ or $n+1$ (except one integer). I need to prove both cases and for which $n$ exactly it exists.

I tried to use many gcd properties on this but didn't find anything...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if $n + 1$ is prime, then
$$GCD = 1$$
else $n + 1$ is composite, if $n + 1 \ne p^2, p$ prime, then
$$\exists a, b \le n\;( a \ne b \wedge n+1 = ab ) \implies n+1 = ab | n! \implies GCD = n+1$$
else if $n + 1 = p^2, p > 2$ prime, then
$$1 < p < 2p \le n \implies p(2p) | n! \implies n+1 = p^2 | n! \implies GCD = n+1$$
else $n + 1 = 2^2$ and
$$GCD = \gcd(3!,4) = 2$$

Conclusion: $GCD = \gcd(n!,n+1) = 1$ or $n+1$ except for the case $n = 3$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: Is $n+1$ prime? What if it is not?

Comment: but what is the only integer it's not exist for?!

Comment: See the excellent answer by @achillehui.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: either $n+1$ is prime or not. The two cases lead to different values.